# How to test for a certain input format

Tags: java, input, format

I'm trying to test if the next line of input from the standard input has the format:

```
integer integer integer
```

with:

```
while(scanner.hasNext("\\d \\d \\d")){
```

If this is the format, then I'll read in the integers and do something with them in the while loop.  If the next line is not that format, then I know to do something else, so the loop will break.  However, my code never enters the while loop.  Did I not specify the line format with regex correctly?

Answer (score 2):

In all likelyhood, you mean to use the following regex:

```
while(scanner.hasNext("\\d+ \\d+ \\d+"))
```

Your regex checks specifically for single-digit numbers.

Comment: He should also guard against varying kinds of whitespace between the digits:  "\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+"

Answer (score 0):

For input such as `1 2 3`, the `hasNext(String pattern)` will only check the first token, i.e. `1`, which will not match your pattern.
You can accomplish what you are trying to do in a slightly different way:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
while ((line = scanner.nextLine()).matches("\\d \\d \\d")) {
    System.out.println("A match!: " + line);
}
```

@Dolda2000 has a valid point too. Unless you are looking for three single-digit integers only, you want his pattern instead.

Comment: Alright, and I just found out that the last number in the row has to be a double, so what is the regex code for that?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and my while loop still will not run. Here is what I have:
while ((line = scanner.nextLine()).matches("\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d"))
                                                                   It still will not match the layout of each line for some reason

Comment: For a double as last entry you can use `\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+(\\.\\d+)?`, which allows an optional fraction part to the last entry. Do you have any extra spaces at the end or something? This works fine for me.